# How to solve the "Multiple object sets per type are not supported" problem with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to build a code first `dbcontext` for my FHEM database.

This database consists of two tables `current` and `history` with exactly the same schema. The SQL create commands are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE current 
( 
     TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, 
     DEVICE varchar(64), 
     TYPE varchar(64), 
     EVENT varchar(512), 
     READING varchar(64), 
     VALUE varchar(128), 
     UNIT varchar(32)
)

CREATE TABLE history 
( 
     TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, 
     DEVICE varchar(64), 
     TYPE varchar(64), 
     EVENT varchar(512), 
     READING varchar(64), 
     VALUE varchar(128), 
     UNIT varchar(32)
)
```

So the `dbcontext` should look like this:

```
  public class FhemContext : DbContext
  {
        public virtual DbSet<LogEntries> History { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LogEntries> Current{ get; set; }
  }
```

The `LogEntries` class does not quite fit into the Entity Framework table concept, but should be like this:

```
public class History
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string DEVICE { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EVENT { get; set; }
    public string READING { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public string UNIT { get; set; }
}
```

To fit into the schema, I think I would have to add a property `currentId' or 'historyId' with type int.

But that's another problem.

How must I declare the class `FhemContext` to satisfy the Entity Framework restrictions and also comply with the original database schema of FHEM?

- Perhaps I should add a marker column that defines whether the row is a current or history row? But the idea behind these two tables seems to be that access to the current table will always be faster than to the history because of the row count.

Greetings Wolfgang

Here is the code that works for me right now:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    [Key]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string DEVICE { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EVENT { get; set; }
    public string READING { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public string UNIT { get; set; }
}

public class Current : LogEntry
{
}

public class History : LogEntry
{
}

public class FhemContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<History> History { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Current> Current{ get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new FhemContext();
        Console.WriteLine(db.Current.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(db.History.Count());

        History historyentry = new History { Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
        db.History.Add(historyentry);
        db.SaveChanges();

        Current currentEntry = new Current{ Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
        db.Current.Add(currentEntry);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a one-to-many relationship between Current and History? Or are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: both tables contain the same data. current contains only the last couple of hours /  days or months and history does contain all data.

Comment: @marc_s, I hate it when other people try to correct my post. Please revert your changes.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, Wolfgang - I only fixed a few typos and wrong upper-/lower casing to make things look nicer and more polished and more approachable for readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help?

```
public class FhemContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<History> History { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Current> Current{ get; set; }
}

public class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string DEVICE { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EVENT { get; set; }
    public string READING { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public string UNIT { get; set; }
}

public class Current : LogEntry
{
}

public class History : LogEntry
{
}
```

And the map the type History to the table history and so forth.

Comment: This resembles my try. You made a base class for both table classes, whereas I inherited one of my table class from the other. But then I got the marker column auto created. Your solution seems to fit best.

Comment: what do you mean `And the map the type History to the table history and so forth.` It seems to work like it is now..

Comment: Then it's perfect :)

Comment: Just one more comment... Is it plausible that adding a  single row could cost 70 milliseconds? My Sqlite Database has more than 2e6 rows, so this would take a while to convert and save...